# Identify main text in website article

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, nlp

I would like to know if there is some tool that given a url to a blog/webpage it identifies and extract the main text. Because an article page, say a blog post, may have different parts of text, one of this part is the article itself. There is a way to identify and extract it?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the world of web scraping.  Short answer: No, there is no standard way to do this.  You can make some good guesses, but any measure of accuracy is going to require reverse-engineering the markup for that specific page to extract the specific content you want and hoping the page structure doesn't change in later requests.

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps for this problem:

1. Retrieve the data from the URL
2. Extract article text (removing ads ...)
3. Summarize the text

1 is easily done with Python [urllib2.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).

If you know the structure of the web site (main HTML tags and such) this can be easily done with tools such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Removing ads in generic way is a bigger subject - you can find some research on the subject online.

Creating a summary by extracting sentences is well known field. I *think* [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) has some modules to do that. You can even take a look at [a simple (and effective) approach](http://pythonwise.blogspot.co.il/2008/01/simple-text-summarizer.html) I wrote a while back.

Comment: Yes, we can do that in a well known web site, where we know the HTML structure. I was asking for a general solution that works in every web site (at least in those related with media industry, such as blogs, newspapers, etc.)

BTW, I don't understand the down votes. Is this question that ridiculous?

Comment: No sure about the down votes, maybe there's a similar question already answered?

Comment: Maybe there's a way to "lock" this post because there is a similar question already answered? Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX call to grab the content, but you have to be on the same domain. You can't copy someone else's content.

Alternatively, grab it with PHP using

```
$content = file_get_contents('{filename}');
```

and then use the html tag (e.g. '<section>') to split it.

What are you using it for? Because if it is your content, I would use ajax and always put the content you want to grab in a tag with a specific class assigned. If it is someone else's content then you might want to ask their permission first.